# ParseException: Unparseable date

Tags: java, datetime, simpledateformat

Why am I getting this exception?

see my code

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

        DateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-y", Locale.ENGLISH);
        DateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date date = originalFormat.parse("09-Dec-2013");
        String formattedDate = targetFormat.format(date); 

        System.out.println(formattedDate);


    }

}
```

What i Wanted ?

input : 09-Dec-2013
  Expected Out put : `2013-12-09` Or `2013-12-09 00:00:00` // (any of this two)

Thanks.

Comment: `originalFormat.parse("09-7-3");` . Provide date as you have specified in the formatter. but does not make sense correct use formatter as `dd-mm-yy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this ...

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

    DateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    DateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date date = originalFormat.parse("09-Dec-2013");
        String formattedDate = targetFormat.format(date); 

        System.out.println(formattedDate);


    }
```

}

the output will be :2013-12-09

Answer (score 0):

change

```
DateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-y", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

to

```
DateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

[Working code](http://ideone.com/1792y8)

If you want in this format `2013-12-09 00:00:00` then see [this](http://ideone.com/sTdtZW)

Comment: @user2210064 see the link in my answer

Comment: @user2210064 see the 2nd link for your 2nd way

Answer (score 0):

Change to the `dd-MMM-yyyy` format

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

    DateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    DateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date date = originalFormat.parse("09-Dec-2013");
    String formattedDate = targetFormat.format(date);

    System.out.println(formattedDate);
}
```